# fscanf and structure alignment

Tags: c++, c

I came across a weird bug recently while debugging my code. I had a structure that looked something like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint8  val1;
    uint16 val2;
    uint8  val3;
    uint8  val4;
    uint16 val5;
    uint8  val6;
} foo;
```

where `uint8` and `uint16` were defined as `unsigned char` and `unsigned short int` respectively. I was trying to scan from a tab separated text file using `fscanf`. The code went something like this :

```
foo f;
FILE* fptr = fopen("test.txt", "r");

if (fptr == NULL)
{
    printf("Error opening file");
    return;
}

if (6 == fscanf(fptr, "val2=%hu\t"
    "val1=%u\t"
    "val3=%u\t"
    "val4=%u\t"
    "val5=%hu\t"
    "val6=%u", &f.val2, &f.val1, &f.val3, &f.val4, &f.val5, &f.val6))
    {
        //Some other code
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error");
    }
    fclose(fptr);
```

While debugging, I found that the value stored in `val2` was `0` no matter what format specifiers I used or what I entered in the text file. I managed to fix the bug by switching `val1` and `val2` in the definition of `foo`. What I didn't understand was why this arose in the first place.

I'm guessing it's got something to do with alignment, but I'd really appreciate it if someone could give a good explanation of exactly what was happening in the first case.

Comment: Nothing to do with alignment. Your format specifiers are all messed up, causing undefined behavior. `%u` is `unsigned int`, `%hu` is `unsigned short`, and `%hhu` is `unsigned char`.

Comment: Your format specifiers don't match the type sizes.

Comment: I tried using %hhu instead of %u as well. That didn't work either.

Comment: @npn [Works for me](http://ideone.com/XrNPBQ).

Comment: Just a thought: are you heeding to the [Endian God](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing a pointer to an 8-bit variable (val1) to scanf with a format specifier for a 32-bit type causes fscanf to write past the end of the variable, and hence, over the top of the adjacent member(s) of the structure (val2 and val3).

%u is unsigned int so scanf() thinks it has a 4 byte address to store its value to. Instead, it is potentially writing data into the memory address of 2 other variables.